# CSS responsive card without bootstrap

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I would like to create a responsive card in HTML and CSS without using bootstrap like this:

[image: sample card]

Comment: please go through https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/themeshaper.com/2014/08/19/why-bootstrap-is-a-bad-fit-for-wordpress-themes/amp/ ... it may help you

Comment: Ok. So, what is the issue you are facing with it? [Learn how to ask a proper question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Shows lack of research done on the issue/requirement.

Comment: then write your own media queries and classes, please research about it first

Comment: This is not a question. It’s a request for other people to do your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd be better to use `flex` like this:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
}

.container div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}

.picture {
  background: #4451c2;
}

.text {
  background: #f451c2;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .container div {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="picture">picture</div>
  <div class="text">Some text is here</div>
</div>
```

With `@media` rule where we will change `width` to `100%` and `flex-order` to `column`.

P.S.: don't pay attention to the blocks's height, this is just for example how to solve your problem with screen size.